# Weird performance of my code of 4*4 Kakuro Puzzle

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I was trying to write the code of performing 4*4 Kakuro puzzles using concept of optimzation. Basically it requires the sum of empty cells in each row and column equal to the first entry of that row or column. For example, if the given puzzle is

```
np.array([[ 0., 21., 20.,  10.],
                [23.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 19.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 9.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]), 

then the output should be 
np.array([[ 0., 21., 20.,  10.],
                [23.,  9.,  8.,  6.],
                [ 19.,  7.,  9.,  3.],
                [ 9.,  5.,  3.,  1.]]).
```

My code is able to run, but the output seems very weird and I couldn't find its excecuting pattern at all. Here is my code.

```
def Kakuro(M):
    
    prob = pulp.LpProblem() 
    rows = range(1,4)
    cols = range(1,4)
    vals = range(1,10)

    X = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("X",(rows,cols,vals),cat='Binary')

    for i in rows:
        for j in cols:
            prob += sum([X[i][j][k] for k in vals]) == 1
            
    for i in rows:
        prob += sum([X[i][j][k] for j in cols for k in vals]) == M[i,0]

    for j in cols:
        prob += sum([X[i][j][k] for i in rows for k in vals]) == M[0,j]


    prob.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0))

    solution = np.zeros((4,4))
    for i in rows:
      solution[i,0] = M[i,0]
    for j in cols:
      solution[0,j]=M[0,j]

    for i in rows:
        for j in cols:
            for k in vals:
                if X[i][j][k].value() == 1:
                    solution[i,j] = k
    
    return solution
```

And the output of example above is

```
array([[ 0., 21., 20., 10.],
       [23.,  2.,  6.,  3.],
       [19.,  5.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 9.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I don't know where these arbitrary numbers come from. Any help would be very appreciated!

---

If you do not understand about my constriants, please feel free to ask me.Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the solution status after solve?  I'm betting it says infeasible...  You appear to be using the binary variable `x` to indicate selection of the value of `k` in a particular position....  But in your row and column sum, I believe you need to multiply `x` by the value `k` to get the value in the summation.

Comment: Great. You would probably get better performance (if you care…. It is a small model) by reformulating and getting rid of the binary variables and just declaring ‘x’ to be an integer between 0 and whatever upper limit

Answer (score 0):

Please see the solution below. I have used Google-ortool's CP-SAT solver.

```
import numpy as np
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp

input_data_matrix = np.array([[ 0, 21, 20,  10],
                            [23,  0,  0,  0],
                            [ 19,  0,  0,  0],
                            [ 9,  0,  0,  0]])

num_rows = len(input_data_matrix)
num_columns = [len(i) for i in input_data_matrix][0]
max_value_matrix = max([input_data_matrix[row][col] for row in range(num_rows) for col in range(num_columns)])

model = cp.CpModel()

dv_zero = {}
for row in range(num_rows):
    for col in range(num_columns):
        if col > 0 and input_data_matrix[row][col] == 0:
            dv_zero[row, col] = model.NewIntVar(1, 9, str(row) + "_" + str(col))
       
for row in np.unique([k[0] for k in dv_zero]):
    dvs = [v for k,v in dv_zero.items() if k[0] == row]
    model.AddAllDifferent(dvs)
    value = sum([input_data_matrix[row][col] for col in range(num_columns) if col not in [k[1] for k,v in dv_zero.items() if k[0] == row]])
    model.Add(sum(dvs) == value)
    
for col in np.unique([k[1] for k in dv_zero]):
    dvs = [v for k,v in dv_zero.items() if k[1] == col]
    model.AddAllDifferent(dvs)
    value = sum([input_data_matrix[row][col] for row in range(num_rows) if row not in [k[0] for k,v in dv_zero.items() if k[1] == col]])
    model.Add(sum(dvs) == value)
    
solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)
    
# inspect the solution :
for row in range(num_rows):
    for col in range(num_columns):
        if col > 0 and input_data_matrix[row][col] == 0:
            print("row: " + str(row) + " ; col: " + str(col) + " = " + str(solver.Value(dv_zero[row, col])))
        else:
            print("row: " + str(row) + " ; col: " + str(col) + " = " + str(input_data_matrix[row][col]))
```